# Is there a good DAL or DAL/ORM for Node.js yet?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, node.js, heroku

I want to experiment a bit with Heroku and Node.js. Heroku uses Postgres by default but I would like the option to use Amazon RDS later on (MySQL). Is there a good database abstraction layer, preferably with a simple object relational mapper around it available at this point? I checked the NPM repository, but couldn't find something that supported both, looked mature and was well documented.

Comment: Are you looking for a database agnostic DAL? There are plenty of wrappers / ORMs for specific databases.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in using another hosting provider. For example Duostack is super easy to set up and allows the usage of mysql: http://docs.duostack.com/node/databases#mysql

An ORM for MySQL is e.g. sequelize ( http://sequelizejs.com | https://github.com/sdepold/sequelize ).